# textview отображение текста посередине на планшете

Tags: java, android

Помогите разобраться с отображением textview на планшете. Код текствью:

```
<TextView
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/confirmCode"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Тестирую на Lenovo A6010 и Samsung Tab2. На планшете текст вью находится слева, а на телефоне по центру. Я что-то упускаю. Подскажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему он у вас и на телефоне не по центру, а тоже слева (но экран мал и кажется по центру), т.к. вы проставили ему:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Так что скорее всего убирание вышеозначенных атрибутов решит вашу проблему.

Comment: Вы правы! Спасибо